# I want to add separate panels (using JPanel) in my code using gridbag layout .Can anyone one suggest me with the right code.Thanks in advance

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am unable to add panels separately to the components.Can you help me with the right code please.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Example3 extends JPanel  
{
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public Example3()
    {
          setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          constraints.weightx = 1.0;
          constraints.weighty = 1.0;
          constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
          constraints.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
          int x, y;  

          // Iwant to add panel to this section to the left side//
          constraints.gridheight = 1;
          addGB(new JLabel("label1"),   x = 0, y = 0);
          addGB(new JLabel("label2"),   x = 0, y = 1);
          addGB(new JLabel("label3"),   x = 0, y = 2);
          addGB(new JLabel("label4"),   x = 0, y = 3);
          addGB(new JLabel("label5"),   x = 0, y = 4);

          //i want another panel to add to this section to the bottom//
           constraints.gridwidth=2;
          addGB(new JTextField("txt1"),     x=1, y=0);
          addGB(new JButton("btn1"),        x=1, y=1);
          addGB(new JRadioButton("no"),     x=1, y=2);
          addGB(new JRadioButton("no"),     x=1, y=2);
          addGB(new JComboBox(),            x=1, y=3);
          addGB(new JTextField("txt3"),     x=1, y=4);
          addGB(new JButton("OK"),          x=1, y=5);

          //I want to add panels to this section in the center//
          addGB(new JCheckBox("chk1"),     x=3, y=0); 
          addGB(new JCheckBox("chk2"),     x=3, y=1);
          addGB(new JTextArea("txtar1"),   x=3, y=2);
          addGB(new JRadioButton("rbtn2"), x=3, y=3);
          addGB(new JComboBox(),           x=3, y=4);
          addGB(new JButton("CANCEL"),     x=3, y=5);

          //I want to add panel to this section to right side//         
          addGB(new JCheckBox("chk3"),     x=5, y=0);
          addGB(new JCheckBox("chk4"),     x=7, y=0);

      }

      void addGB(Component component, int x, int y) 
      {
          constraints.gridx = x;
          constraints.gridy = y;
          add(component, constraints);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Example3");
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
           frame.setSize(200, 200);
           frame.setLocation(200, 200);
           frame.setContentPane(new Example3());
           frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

I want to add panels to labels separately and  checkboxes separately using gridbag layout,JPanel.Can anyone suggest me  with the right code please.

Comment: Please format your code properly by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Also, you should be more specific about how you want to use panels (do you mean `JPanel`?) and only share the most relevant code. We probably don't need to see _every single_ function call to `addGB`.

Comment: Hi Arc676 I want to add using gridbag lay out using JPanel

Answer (score 1):

If you wont just to add JPanel you can add this code in your main

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Example3");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  .....
  //you miss those line
  JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
  frame.getContentPane().add(p);
```

Comment: Hi Abdelhak.Thank you for your comment.One more ques please. instead of addGB in my code if I add "p" inplace of "addGB" is panel is added to labels ..

Comment: Hi Abdelhak.for too many panels can I write code like this  JPanel p1=new JPanel();     frame.getContentPane().add(p1);

Comment: Hi Abdelhak.I tried your solution but not getting to the right point.Iam new to  swings.Can you please write one sample code for me. I want to place some components in gridbag layout and that components should be in separate panels with border.I tried but Iam not getting the right output.Can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PizzaGridBagLayout extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PizzaGridBagLayout();
  }

  JTextField name = new JTextField(10), phone = new JTextField(10);JComboBox address = new JComboBox(new String[]{"ComboBox 1","hi","hello"});
  JComboBox address1 = new JComboBox(new String[]{"ComboBox 2","hi","hello"});
  JButton labels=new JButton("labels");
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1"); 
          JLabel  label2 = new JLabel("label2");
                  JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
                  JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Label4");
                  JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Label5");



    JRadioButton  yes = new JRadioButton("yes"),
      no = new JRadioButton("no");

  JCheckBox box1 = new JCheckBox("box1"), box2 = new JCheckBox("box2"),
      box3 = new JCheckBox("box3");


  JButton okButton = new JButton("OK"), closeButton = new JButton("Close");

  public PizzaGridBagLayout() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //addItem(panel1, new JLabel(""), 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
   // addItem(panel1, new JLabel(""), 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
   // addItem(panel1, new JLabel(""), 1, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

    addItem(panel1, name, 1, 2, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(panel1, phone, 1, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(panel1, address, 1, 4, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
    addItem(panel1, address1, 1, 6, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

   Box sizeBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    //ButtonGroup sizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    //sizeGroup.add(label1);
    //sizeGroup.add(label2);
    //sizeGroup.add(label3);
    //sizeGroup.add(label4);
    //sizeGroup.add(label5);
    sizeBox.add(label1);
    sizeBox.add(label2);
    sizeBox.add(label3);
    sizeBox.add(label4);
    sizeBox.add(label5);
    sizeBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    addItem(panel1, sizeBox, 0, 3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);

    addItem(panel1, label1, 0, 3, 1, 1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
    addItem(panel1, label2, 0, 4, 1, 1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
    addItem(panel1, label3, 0, 5, 1, 1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
    addItem(panel1, label4, 0, 6, 1, 1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
    addItem(panel1, label5, 0, 7, 1, 1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);

    /*Box sizeBox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    ButtonGroup sizeGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
    sizeBox1.add(labels);
    addItem(panel1, sizeBox1, 0, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);*/

    Box styleBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
   // ButtonGroup styleGroup = new ButtonGroup();
   // styleGroup.add(yes);
   // styleGroup.add(no);
   styleBox.add(yes);
   styleBox.add(no);
   styleBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    addItem(panel1, styleBox, 1, 3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);

    Box topBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    ButtonGroup topGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    //topGroup.add(box1);
    //topGroup.add(box2);
    //topGroup.add(box3);
    topBox.add(box1);
    topBox.add(box2);
    //topBox.add(box3);
    topBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    addItem(panel1, topBox, 2, 3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);

    Box buttonBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    buttonBox.add(okButton);
    addItem(panel1, buttonBox, 1, 6, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
    buttonBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
    buttonBox.add(closeButton);
    addItem(panel1, buttonBox, 2, 7, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);

    this.add(panel1);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align) {
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = x;
    gc.gridy = y;
    gc.gridwidth = width;
    gc.gridheight = height;
    gc.weightx = 100.0;
    gc.weighty = 100.0;
    gc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    gc.anchor = align;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(c, gc);
  }
}
```

Comment: guys I got an answer for the question which I raised before that is how to add multiple panels in a frame using gridbag layout.